# Julia: Passing arguments to quandl function through the map() function

Tags: programming, market-data, yahoofinance

I am new to julia, and I am trying to use "map()" to apply the function "quandl" on an array of (n x 1) stock tickers. (http://quandljl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_data.html)

However, I wish to pass on more than just the tickers as arguments to the function, such as "from = Date1" and "to = Date2" to download daily prices for a specific time interval.

I cannot seem to find a way to have map() apply the function on the array of strings while also passing the keyword arguments to download data from Date1 to Date2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, all the credit goes to user StefanKarpinski. Follow the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906788/julia-passing-arguments-to-function-through-the-map-function